Rotten subfloor under wall frame
I have rotten subfloor under my shower. I removed the shower and and I understand the general process of replacing the subfloor. In this case, there is rot underneath an interior wall frame (which contains plumbing and electric). Should I also replace the wall? Maybe try to replace the footer of the wall? I'm assuming the studs are nailed into the rotten part. Any advice is appreciated.


The first thing you need to do is get your circular saw out and start removing the plywood flooring so you know the extent of the damage. Removing it at seams will make installing new wood easier. It looks like the sill plate will have to be partially replaced but the studs look OK. If the wall isn't load bearing, remove the corner studs or stagger cut so you can sister them back. Then cut the sill plate back toward the cable, being carefull not to cut it. Then you can further remove the rotton wood under the sill plate to the joists which hopefully will be rot free. Install new plywood and sill plate section and sister or replace corner studs.
